# How do I add stickers or labels to my product image?

Tags: image, product-list

How do I add stickers or labels or watermark to my product image?
Does anyone know any good module for adding stickers to the products?

Comment: do you want to add watermark on your image or just a label to a image?

Answer (score 1):

You Can add watermark on product images.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried but here is a [step-by-step how-to](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-add-new-and-sale-products-attributes.html).